# php get value based on key in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to get a new array with all the codes that I get from an array called $houses. I loop thru it. To get the codes I tried `$house['code']` This works in the dd but not in the `$code = $house['code']`.
I would like to know why and what the solution to this is.

```
$houses = $project['data']['houses'];
$codes = [];

foreach($houses as $house) {
    $code = array_column($house, 'code');
    //dd($house['code']);  //Returns the code "AB12-CD34-EF56-GH78"
    if(!$code) {
        continue;
    } else {
        array_push($codes, $code);
    }
}

dd($codes); //Returns []
```

EDIT:
var_dump $houses:

```
array:60 [
0 => array:30 [
    "id" =>
    "city" => ""
    "code" => "AB12-CD34-EF56-GH78"
    "streetName" => ""
    "houseNumber" => ""
    //And some other stuff that is not relevant to the question
]
]
```

Comment: And what's the point in using `array_column`? Maybe just `$codes = array_column($houses, 'code');` is __enough__?

Comment: What does the `dd()` function do?

Comment: Show us the var_dump of `$houses`

Comment: @WasteD dump and die

Comment: @u_mulder I was willing to try everything

Comment: Maybe if you show us the content of `$project['data']['houses']` we could better help you

Comment: @WasteD I commented it in the code

Comment: Show us `$project['data']['houses']`

Comment: @ascsoftw I edited the question to show the var_dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this loop, you can simply extract all `code`s from subarrays with:

```
$houses = $project['data']['houses'];
$codes = array_column($houses, 'code');
dd($codes);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Will accept in a min.
Will it still work if I have for example 200 houses?

Comment: It will work with __any__ size of houses, considering you have enough memory.

Answer (score 2):

`array_column` is for recovering a column from an array inside an array of arrays. `$house` is a simple array and doesn't contain arrays in it. just use `$house['code']`

```php
$houses = $project['data']['houses'];
$codes = [];

foreach($houses as $house) {
    if(isset($house['code']) && $house['code']) {
        $codes[] = $house['code'];
    }
}

dd($codes); //Returns ["AB12-CD34-EF56-GH78","AB12-CD34-EF56-GH79", ....]
```

Comment: @WasteD he also said `//dd($house['code']);  //Returns the code "AB12-CD34-EF56-GH78"`